# How to build a portable class library without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, msbuild, uwp

I'm trying to build a portable library project on a TFS server and I've got the following error:

> "The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable\v4.6\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk"

It's true, I don't have a Portable directory in MSBuild/Microsoft on the server. I have it on my developer computer, so I guess if I install Visual Studio it will work but I don't want to. I've installed the build tools on the server, with all the available UWP features but I still don't have this Portable directory.

Answer (score 0):

In general, your build server should consist of the same software configuration as a developer workstation. Install Visual Studio. It does not consume a license.

Comment: If it's the only way to have what I need, I have no problem with that. I just want to be sure that I didn't miss any SDK/Tools/Whatever to install.

Comment: @ Clément Picou Just install Visual Studio, build tools is not perfect for now, see the [user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/5786689-support-net-builds-without-requiring-visual-studi)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable folder to your build server. It's pity that build tools 2017 don't create these files automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install just [.NET Framework Developer Pack 4.6.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321), the Build tools essentials from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159), and [PortableLibraryTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BCLTeam.PortableLibraryTools2) with `/buildmachine` switch?